# How to add to surefire report positive steps in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, surefire

I'm using surefire reports to document my JUnit test.
I want to create something like test log after execution of JUnit data, but I have no idea how I can add additional data to surefire report without breaking the test.
Somebody have any Idea? Maybe I should use something else than surefire?